# SQL/MySQL - Update target table with most recent entry

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I'm looking for some help with a SQL/MySQL problem.

I have three source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `cid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
CREATE TABLE `standards` (
  `sid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `standard_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
CREATE TABLE `partial_standard_compliance` (
  `customer` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `standard` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `standard_compliance` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The idea is a customer gives themselves a rating using the standard_compliance column in the partial_standard_compliance table.
Customers can rate the same standard multiple times.
Result example:

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| customer | standard | standard_compliance | created_time        |
+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        1 |        1 |                  50 | 2023-01-28 16:19:34 |
|        1 |        1 |                  60 | 2023-01-28 16:19:40 |
|        1 |        1 |                  70 | 2023-01-28 16:19:48 |
|        2 |       10 |                  30 | 2023-01-28 16:58:21 |
|        2 |        8 |                  60 | 2023-01-28 16:58:32 |
|        2 |        9 |                  60 | 2023-01-28 16:58:39 |
|        2 |        9 |                  80 | 2023-01-28 16:58:43 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to create a 4th table that has customer name, standard name and the most recent rating they have given themselves.
I have been trying with JOINS and CREATE AS SELECT, but haven't been able to solve it.
Any point in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

I have been trying with JOINS and CREATE AS SELECT

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a 4th table that has customer name, standard name and
> the most recent rating they have given themselves

Would be better if you create a view instead.

```
create view fourth_table as
select customer_name ,
       standard_name , 
       standard_compliance,
       created_time
from (select c.customer_name,
             s.standard_name,
             psc.standard_compliance,
             psc.created_time,
             row_number() over(partition by  c.customer_name order by psc.created_time desc ) as rn
      from customers c 
      inner join partial_standard_compliance psc on psc.customer=c.cid
      inner join standards s on s.sid=psc.standard
     ) x
where rn=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ZiK-k8jN

[MySQL View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)